# Валидация значения введенного в поле

Tags: html

У меня есть несколько полей, которые вводит пользователь. Все поля находятся в форме. По клику на кнопку отправить, я делаю POST-запрос на сервер. На сервере данные проверяются на корректность. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы если данные ввелись не верно, форма не скидывалась? Сейчас у меня по клику "отправить" перезагружается все страничка. Как это исправить?

UPD В клиентском коде отвалидировать значения невозможно, к примеру, капчу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно либо отсылать форму аяксом, либо отсылать форму на ту же страницу и при выводе формы выводить значения из $_POST'а. Пример: `<input type="text" name="param1" value="<?=$_POST['param1']?>">` .

Comment: Самый разумный способ из предложенных.

Comment: делаю так всегда :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#contacts button').click(function(){ //собираем введеные значения используя аттрибуты name
                var name = textBoxes.filter('[name=name]').val();
                var mail = textBoxes.filter('[name=mail]').val();
                var subject = textBoxes.filter('[name=subject]').val();
                var msg = textBoxes.filter('[name=msg]').val();
                if(name==""||mail==""||subject==""||msg==""){ $('.error').show(300) } else { $('.error').hide(300);  //самая простая валидация,использовать на рабочем сайте не рекоммендуется

                    $.getJSON('letter.php', {name:name,mail:mail,subject:subject,msg:msg}, 
                        function(obj){ //функция отвечающая за успех
                            сюда присылается ответ в формате json от сервера
$('#answer').html(obj);
                        });

                }
                return false
            });
```

Взял из тестового задания для для js junior.

Answer (score 0):

Можно изначально отключить кнопку, затем использовать плагин `jQuery Validation`. Следить за изменением полей и, если все верно, делать кнопку доступной для щелчка.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.